# Java среда разработки для Windows 3.1

Tags: java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, среду разработки Java, чтобы она работала под Windows 3.1 и разрабатывать соответсвенно под нее.

Comment: (facepalm) олдСкул неправильно написано, чем тебе просто компилятор неугодил? блокнот чем не среда разработки? пробовал еклипс?

Comment: В [этом][1] списке есть Java SDK для windows 3.11


  [1]: http://www.gaby.de/win3x/esoft.htm

Очень интересно зачем Вам это нужно...Расскажите?

Comment: И мне интересно .....

Comment: Windows 3.1? Вы готовитесь к переброске в прошлое? (А, я понял -- спасаетесь от конца света!)

Comment: @KryDos я кстати именно оттуда SDK качал, а мне хотелось бы IDE. Возможно я двояко выразился сказав «среда разработки». Нужно что-то похожее на IDE минимум с автодополнением кода.

Comment: Есть реальные машины под этой ОС и это не изменить :)  
@vladD, скорее прошлое меня догнало :) Могу на QBasice еще под 3.1 писать, но у меня от него пальцы мандражируют :)  
@gorets Мне кажется эклипс не запустить хотя бы потому, что eclipse.exe не под эту архитектуру сделан.

Comment: @ReinRaus, ну я сомневаюсь, что можно найти нечто подобное.

Comment: @gorets поправил тэги :)

Comment: @ReinRaus и java-то в SDK сильно не такая, как сейчас, а от Microsoft. Там не jar'ы, а zip'ы. Вероятность найти какую-то IDE для java весьма невелика. И ещё, если Windows 3.1, то насчёт win32s под неё я тоже не уверен (w3.1 и win3.1x -- разные системы)

QBasic был под dos, под винды был уже vb. Ну и Borland C++/Borland Pascal

Comment: Это что какая-то промышленная машинка типа кассового терминала или банкомата или того хуже пульт управления системой вентилирования здания (недавно сталкивался)?

Comment: поправьте меня если я ошибаюсь, но java появилась в 1995, тогда как win3.1 теоретически сдулся (прошу прощения, застал только win95 по детству). Собственно я немного в растерянности, будет ли исполнятся java код на данной ОС?

Comment: @Viacheslav ага. win3.1 -- год 1992, java первого разлива -- 1995, jbilder 4.0 -- 2000г. "И как же это ёжики размножаются -- тут иголки -- и тут иголки..."

Comment: @alexlz народ под 3.1 сидел долго вплоть до конца 90-х. Чтобы далеко не ходить Windows XP вышел в 2001-м и до сих пор половина офисного планктона сидит под ним и не жужжит - у нас в офисе 7-ку имеет не более 10% - так что не надо "ля-ля". Во вторых бета версии Java уже выходили в 94-м году - лично тренировался под ними. Лучше помогите найти/скачать JBuilder древних версий

Comment: Когда у меня была реальная машина под слакварью времен моего прадедушки, и надо было с ней работать, то я не стал заниматься некроархеологией, а засунул оно в виртуалку, и сбоку развел современную систему со всеми удобствами. Чего и всем советую.

Comment: @Barmaley раскройте коммерческую тайну -- нафига win3.1 до конца 90х? Единственное, что приходит в голову -- заметная часть парка компов -- 286е.

Comment: >народ под 3.1 сидел долго вплоть до конца 90-х.

Хо, я работал в лаборатории, где машина под 3.1 использовалась примерно до 2005 г., пока я не убедил начальника засунуть ее подальше на шкаф (причем на мои просьбы списать ее и вынести на помойку он дал отказ, типа, память о минувших годах и все тако.)). Вот так.

Comment: А я знаю одну организацию, которая продает компьютеры на базе 386 с win 3.1 на борту по цене современных супер-пупер топовых игровых компьютеров. И наверно даже чуть подороже.  
И покупают у них.

Comment: на мой вопрос так никто и не ответил толком, java код будет выполнятся на win 3.1 ?

Comment: @Viacheslav Смотря какой "java код". jvm тоже развивается. "java-байткод" середины 90х -- думаю, что да. Современный -- вряд ли.

@ReinRaus как там писал @mikillskegg? "Компания весёлых извращенцев"?

Comment: @alexlz, не, это собиратели антиквариата. Хоть, может быть, и нет...

Comment: @mikillskegg не думаю, что это коллекционеры. Просто до сих пор есть масса старого железа/софта, которое работает в самых неожиданных местах. Сам лично вижу почти каждый день панель доступа к Building Management System который работает на Win2000 - работает и не жужжит. Как-то разбирался с банкоматом вся начинка которого была сделана на IBM OS/2 - таких примеров масса.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Поищите в [Borland JBuilder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JBuilder) 4.0/5.0 - замечательно работал под Windows 3.1

Уверен, валяется в каком-нибудь торренте. Если не найдете выложу из своих архивов, давеча разбирал и видел CDROM с дистрибутивом.

**Update**

После жосткого троллинга [[@alexlz](/users/352/alexlz)](/users/352/alexlz) :) - я чото засомневался и стал вспоминать боевую молодость. Точно помню, что под Win 95/98 работал JBuilder 4/5 (в версии могу ошибаться), под Win 3.1/3.11 не буду ничего утверждать... Надо пробовать.

Comment: @alexlz яфшоке

1) Упаси боже - какая же это шутка? Я помню что JBuilder 4/5 точно работал под Win95/98, насчет 3.1 уже не упомню, но не вижу причин почему не должен работать.

2) Про минусы: ставьте - это ваше законное право, только сначала надо убедиться что жибильдер 4-й не пашет под Win 3.1 - иначе это называется троллинг. Вот спецом найду время на днях и проверю на виртуалке работает или нет! Правда надо будет найти дистрибутив Win 3.1 - что проблематично... да и какая виртуалка это поддержит?

Comment: @barmaley virtual box держит, но проблема с мышкой- скочет странно, приходится клавиатурой управлять. Спасибо, чуть позже попробую.

Comment: @Barmaley Почему я так написал? win3.1 -- это винды, которые запускались ещё из dos'а. Win9x, хотя и с ограничениями, но win32. Под win3.1x 32-бит приложения работали под win32s (с ограничениями). Как win32s работает под win3.1 -- ещё вопрос, это, кажется последние винды со стандартным режимом (защищённый режим 286+). Речь, разумеется может идти только о режиме 386, но и там -- неизвестно. И вот в ответе вижу 

    Поищите в Borland JBuilder 4.0/5.0 - замечательно работал под Windows 3.1

И какой реакциии Вы ожидали? (Я уж не говорю, что JB 4.0+ -- он с jar'ами, а java win95 -- с zip'ами)

Comment: @RainRaus В игре в русскую рулетку используют револьверы, а не пистолеты с магазинами. java, разумеется, много где есть, но может быть сильно другой (напр. http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Card)

@Barmaley вспомнилось, как в 90е один молодой (повидимому) человек утверждал, что ставил linux на ibm pc xt -- "просто руки надо иметь не кривые" (это про систему, которая может работать на 386+)

Comment: @alexlz а я че-то не догнал: причем тут win32? JB по жизни запускался в JVM'е - если JVM пашет то и JB будет пахать - вопрос только в версии JVM. Под Win 3.1 работал 16-ти разрядный JVM это абсолютно точно

Comment: @alexlz, Ваше ерничанье неуместно. Между прочим, Линукс на XT поставить можно. Только вот нужно ли? Копать в сторону проекта ELKS - Embedded Linux Kernel Systems.

Comment: @gecube. Прошу прощения, не уточнил сразу. Это заявление было опубликовано в конце 90х. Проект ядра на 8086 тогда был далёк от рабочего.

А нужно ли? В те времена был i80186 для встраиваемых приложений. Насколько его команды отличаются от 8086, я не в курсе. linux на arm -- вполне себе вариант для embedded

А то, что это не "такой" линукс -- так это и так ясно. Что опять напоминает об ответе-вопросе @KryDos -- нафига? и где этот заповедник win3.1?

Что касается ёрничанья -- сам вопрос такой.

Comment: @barmaley, посмотрите, пожалуйста, свои архивы, если не затруднит. Не могу найти рабочую ссылку на скачивание :(

Comment: @ReinRaus угу ищу - надо будет разобрать ящик на балконе, должен где-то там валяться :)

Comment: @barmaley, а сколько он примерно весит? Нашел одну ссылку, так там образ 730mb- мне кажется многовато для IDE во времена когда 640 кбайт памяти хватало всем нуждающимся.

Comment: @ReinRaus - жена выкинула коробку со старыми дисками, увы. Нет JB 4.0, а то хотел уже бизнес организовать [как здесь](http://www.emsps.com/oldtools/borjbuilder.htm#jb4). Он должен весить порядка 300 мегов. 700 мег - это явный перебор, может там напихали доки или еще чего-то